# MPI-IO File transfer between compute nodes

Tags: mpi, file-transfer, hpc, mpi-io

How to transfer files from localscrach of one compute to localscratch of another compute node in a cluster using MPI-IO?

Answer (score 1):

That isn't really how MPI-IO works. It's designed for reading and writing files, not necessarily transferring them from one process to another. There are plenty of other tools that will do that for you (`scp`, `sftp`, etc.)

If you really wanted to use MPI, you could read the file on one process, send the byte string to another process with normal `MPI_SEND` and `MPI_RECV`, and write that file back out on another process.